# How to make a app scale the look the same on all devices (android)

Tags: java, android, scale

I'm working on a app but I have a problem were buttons and images stay the same size on all screen size but I need to make the change depending on the size of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

you have to design different layouts for tablets but for rest of the devices this library may help for achieving what you want . 
https://github.com/intuit/sdp